# Function to make cookie expire in 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to write a function to make a cookie expire in 15 minutes. Did I write it correctly? Thanks.

```
setCookieExpireIn("cookieName", "value", 15);

function setCookieExpireIn(cookieName, value, expireIn) {
var now = new Date();
var minutes = expireIn;
now.setTime(now.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + value + "; expires = " + now.toUTCString() + ";";
} //end of function addToCookieAndExpireIn(cookieName, value, expireIn)
```

Comment: Don't assign twice to `document.cookie`.

Comment: Use indentation instead of a comment to mark the end of a function.

Comment: @Bergi I edited it. Is that right now?

Comment: You still assign to `document.cookie` multiple times (I had not noticed that you did it three times before the edit, not just two). Build a string, log it to make sure it looks like you would expect (according to the documentation of `document.cookie`) and the assign it.

Comment: @Bergi Okay. There's just one of them now. Is it correct now?

Comment: Tell me, does it work?

Comment: (It seems you dropped the `=` sign between name and value now)

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I think I fixed it. Is it correct now?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't test it.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? Try it with 1 minute instead of 15, and see if after a minute the cookie is still there?